# Telegram api ошибка dotnet

Tags: c#, .net, linux-mint

Всем привет! 
Сегодня решил попробовать написать бота для Telegram на c#. Использовал dotnet. Написал все правильно, несколько раз сверялся с документацией,но ничего не получалось. Вот код:

```
using System;
using Telegram.Bot;

namespace TelegramBot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var clientBot = new TelegramBotClient("821586573:AAF_24_1Om5n-honjvLQnZwkbG2T2h8Rppo");
            var me = clientBot.GetMeAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine($"Bot id: {me.Id}");
        }
    }
}
```

Все в точности как в документации. Сама ошибка:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Request timed out) ---> Telegram.Bot.Exceptions.ApiRequestException: Request timed out ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.<MakeRequestAsync>d__54`1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient.<MakeRequestAsync>d__54`1.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at TelegramBot.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/anton/Рабочий стол/TelegramBot/Program.cs:line 11
```

Comment: Судя по ошибке - это банальный тайм-аут. Я бы предположил, что это не ошибка кода, а заблокированные сервера роскомнадзором.